# Oracle Express 11g command

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I'm trying to run a SQL command with Oracle Express 11g, and it's giving me an error message:

> no rows selected

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING (DEPARTMENT_ID)
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID < 103
AND EMPLOYEE_ID > 203;
```

Comment: This is not an error message, this is the result of your query - there are no such employees. Do you think this is the wrong result? If so, please explain why.

Comment: By the way, please mark your code as source code.

Comment: How do I mark the code as source code. I'm new and I can't seem to figure it out. Sorry

Comment: In the tag bar, you have an icon like that {}. Marc your code and press it. :-)

Comment: Yes @Mureinik. When I tried to show only one table, it works fine. There are 10 employees with > 103 ID. I think I'm having issue combing two tables, EMPLOYEES & DEPARTMENTS. The question asks: The employee identification number, employee name, and department name for all employees whose identification number is less than 103 OR greater than 203.

Answer (score 2):

> The question asks: The employee identification number, employee name, and department name for all employees whose identification number is less than 103 OR greater than 203.

Your code uses the `and` logical operator instead of the `or` operation. Since a number (the ID, in this case) cannot be both less than 103 and greater than 203, you will get no rows.

Just replace the `and` with an `or` and you should be fine:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM   EMPLOYEES 
JOIN   DEPARTMENTS USING (DEPARTMENT_ID)
WHERE  EMPLOYEE_ID < 103 OR  EMPLOYEE_ID > 203;
-- Here -----------------^
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik. It worked. I understood your explanation also. It is greatly appreciated.